# How do I use WP's jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn WP theme development. And I just learned that WP already has a jQuery version included. Until now I have been using the jQuery from Google's CDN.

So I just now deleted the CDN link from my code. And of course all my jQuery code stopped working.

So I guess I am missing something. What do I need to do if I want to use WordPress's local jQuery?

When I search SE QA and Google all I can find is how to un-register the local jQuery version and then register CDN. But that is not what I want to do. I want to use the local jQuery.

So what am I missing?

Comment: search WPSE before you ask a question. It's great possibility that it has been answered already. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111569

Comment: Well I did search first. And I also said I already been searching in my Question. And all I could find was how to deregister and that was not what I was trying to do  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP's jQuery is not mapped to `$` like you may expect, it is loaded in `noConflict` mode so you'll need to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`, unless you map it yourself.

When you include your js file you'll want to make sure to set jQuery as a dependency as well:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to enqueue jQuery from WP-installation you can:

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Jquery enqueue
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts');
```

Additionally, using this trick you can enqueue jQuery into footer (`wp_footer`)

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Jquery - to the footer of template
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', includes_url('/js/jquery/jquery.js'), false, NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts');
```

---

**UPDATE**

Expanding the answer.

Using [`wp_register_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) you can register your custom scripts. After, they can be [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) by the `$handler`.

Generally it grant a benefit of code length reduction [[Related Answer]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque), but I'd like to emphasize your attention on WordPress pre-registered scripts (local in your meaning).

Visit this Codex Page [[Handles and Their Script Paths Registered by WordPress]](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Handles_and_Their_Script_Paths_Registered_by_WordPress). There you will find a `$handler`'s for jQuery UI and other usefull stuff, that you can enqueue as on example above.